# Conversión DBNull y double?

Tags: c#

Tengo un `DataTable` el cual tiene una columna tipo `double` que se debe rellenar con datos, la cosa es que a veces hay errores con estos datos y para demostrarlo quiero ingresar un `null` en vez de un 0, se supone que esto es posible con `DBNull` el problema recae en que recibo valores del tipo `double?` e intelliSense me dice que no puedo hacer la conversión implícita y quedé atascado en esta conversión. Un ejemplo de código sería el siguiente:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Valor", typeof(double));

double? valorConflictivo = null; // da lo mismo el valor aquí

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

// esto me lanza un error de que no se puede convertir implicitamente uno en otro
dr["Valor"] = valorConflictivo ?? DBNull.Value; 

//También probé con esto, mismo error

dr["Valor"] = valorConflictivo == null ? DBNull.Value : valorConflictivo;
```

alguna idea de como hacer esto?

Comment: Está bien tu condición pero no deberías hacerla ahí,más bien es al momento de pasar el parámetro al insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*valorConflictivo* no es un `Type` directamente compatible con `DBNull.Value` .
Los ternarios deberían devolver dos objetos de un tipo compatible.

EJ: Esto nos data error, ya que **int** y **string** no devuelven mismo type

```
 var t = true ? 1 : "2";
```

Puedes castear a object, *valorConflictivo*  lo cual si seria compatible con `DBNull.Value`

```
  dr["Valor"] = (object)valorConflictivo ?? DBNull.Value;

  dr["Valor"] = valorConflictivo == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)valorConflictivo;
```

Comment: gracias estimado